# automatically delete old Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in which I would  like the old data to be deleted automatically if the time is older than 5 days.
The table looks like this : http://de.share-your-photo.com/e6508ee7a6.
Can someone help me? The below Code does not work

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/connection.php';
$variants_remove='DELETE FROM drucker AS drucker WHERE datediff(now(), drucker.zeit) > 5';
$req = $dbConnect->query($variants_remove);
?>
```

Comment: Tables aren't photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
WHERE drucker.zeit) < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

You could use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()` if you prefer to backup from midnight this morning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write script as same as you have written, and set it on cron. Data will be deleted automatically

Comment: can you be a little clearer? because I do not understand you well

Answer (score 0):

> You can use crontab if your on linux/debain/etc..

open your terminal
and type

```
$ crontab -e
```

this will let you edit all crwonjobs
and the terminal will output something like this:
[image: Crontab edit]
Then you can add a new Cron like this after all `# ...` lines:

```
$ 1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/your/autodelete.php
```

for explanaiton:

```
1: Minute (0-59)
2: Hours (0-23)
3: Day (0-31)
4: Month (0-12 [12 == December])
5: Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])
/path/to/command – Script or command name to schedule
```

if you dont want to use hours and day for example then write a `*` instead of an `Int`

```
$ 50 * * 6 2 /path/to/your/autodelete.php
```

**You can read all [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)**

Comment: i preffer using vitualbox and vagrant for testing its the best environment

Comment: @Henri https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx